# How to implement Certificate Transparency for Xamarin.Android

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, certificate-transparency

I'm  trying this is one week to implement Certificate Transparency for Xamarin.Android but without success, can any one help me with a xamarin exemple or algo similar?

Thanks in advance!

I try use https://github.com/babylonhealth/certificate-transparency-Android by binding this lib but it's a Kotlin lib and cant compile in xamarin.
I try https://github.com/anonyome/certificate-transparency-android without success too

Comment: There are a couple of rules when you bind libraries, have you added all dependencies first you need to add all Xamarin.Support... If there is any plus you need to add this one: Xamarin.Kotlin.StdLib

Comment: I already added "xamarin.kotlin.stlib", but i didnt find kotlin coroutines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a couple of weeks withouts an answer to resolve my problem I resolve to create a Nuget package to validate Certificate transparency and I publish it to Nuget to facilitate a life of same people like me rsrs;
This is the Nuget package to direct add it to your project https://www.nuget.org/packages/khalid.certificate.transparency/1.0.0
And also this is the source code on my repository if same one like to contribute.
https://github.com/kaitbellahs/certificate-transparency-C-
This is the first version and I'm sure will have same errors and bugs, please fill free to report.